# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Download" is denied. in xamarin android

Tags: android, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to generate PDF from byte array. but it's giving issue "access path is denied".
I have already given the permission in manifest file. I am sending my code block please check it for a minute and give some suggestion and feedback so that i can complete it.

```
 private void ObjbtnViewSlip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = objPaySlipViewModel.GetPaySlipByte(GlobalApplicationSession.EmployeeCode, GlobalApplicationSession.CompanyId, selectedPeriod);
        if (File.Exists(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/RSI/PaySlip/temp.pdf") == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/RSI/PaySlip/");
            File.Create(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/RSI/PaySlip/temp.pdf");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/RSI/PaySlip/", result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please change the image to inline code. People can copy-paste the code into an IDE and help you fix it faster.

Comment: @matthewrdev please check. I need your suggestion to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the path that you're giving is incorrect. 
Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads will only return "Download"

Modify your code to get the full path to the downloads folder like :

```
//The following will return the downloads folder path.
string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
string file = Path.Combine(directory, "/RSI/PaySlip/temp.pdf");
```

Also check if the following has been mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml file to grant the permissions to the application.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string localStoragePath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string localFilename = Path.GetFileName(serverFileName);
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localStoragePath, localFilename);

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(localFilePath))
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile(serverFileName, localFilePath);          
            }

            OpenFile(localFilePath);


            });
```

public void OpenFile(string filePath)
        {

```
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        //Copy the private file's data to the EXTERNAL PUBLIC location
        string externalStorageState = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState;
        string application = "";

        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath);

        switch (extension.ToLower())
        {
            case ".doc":
            case ".docx":
                application = "application/msword";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                application = "application/pdf";
                break;
            case ".xls":
            case ".xlsx":
                application = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".jpg":
            case ".jpeg":
            case ".png":
                application = "image/jpeg";
                break;
            default:
                application = "*/*";
                break;
        }
        var externalPath = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/report" + extension;
        File.WriteAllBytes(externalPath, bytes);

        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(externalPath);
        file.SetReadable(true);
        //Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + filePath);
        var uri = global::Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        try
        {
            Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "No Application Available to View PDF", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```